# Next.js make page props smaller using translations

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js, translation

I'm trying to add translations to my next js app, but I have a problem. I get a very heavy translation object from server with 30000 keys to all my app. When I'm passing object through pages props it makes js bundle file bigger because unused translation keys are added too. How can I optimize it?

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you.

Comment: You should split up the object with the language as keys and use dynamic imports (https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports) to only import the currently needed file.